# Getting the uid of exchange calendar item

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices, icalendar, ews-managed-api

Although I've set the property on the view, I cannot retrieve the ical's uid when I write code this way.

```
    static void GetCalendarItem(ExchangeService svc, string iCalUid)
    {
        var view = new ItemView(500);
        var propSet = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.IdOnly);
        propSet.Add(ItemSchema.Subject);
        propSet.Add(MeetingMessageSchema.ICalUid);
        var items = svc.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Calendar, view);
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            var subject = item.Subject;
            var guid = DefaultExtendedPropertySet.PublicStrings;
            var epdUid = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(guid, "UID", MapiPropertyType.Binary);
            string uid = string.Empty;
            var result = false;
            if(item.TryGetProperty<string>(epdUid, out uid))
            {
                result = true; 
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Sub: {0}, Result: {1}", subject, result);
        }
    }
```

I am using managed ews api 2.2. In this example result is always printed `false`.

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple issue with your code, you have created a property set but you haven't set that on the Itemview. Your ExtendedProperty isn't correct unless you have your own extended property with that definition and you haven't loaded it in any EWS operations so i won't ever show any value. You code should look like

```
static void GetCalendarItem(ExchangeService svc, string iCalUid)
{
    var view = new ItemView(500);
    var propSet = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.IdOnly);
    propSet.Add(ItemSchema.Subject);
    propSet.Add(MeetingMessageSchema.ICalUid);
    view.PropertySet = propSet;
    var items = svc.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Calendar, view);
    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        var subject = item.Subject;
        var result = item.ICalUid;


        Console.WriteLine("Sub: {0}, Result: {1}", subject, result);
    }
}
```

Comment: `item` doesn't have a property `ICalUid`